# Iraqiairways.com.iq website is safe or not?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, airlines, iraq

Anyone bought ticket from iraqiairways.com.iq site for Iraq, is it safe ?, and when you pay by credit card , can you print the issued ticket immediadetely after the purchase?

Comment: I like it how you are concerned whether it's safe to buy a ticket with them, not whether it is safe to *actually fly* with them.

Comment: @alamar Why would they not be safe? They're safe enough to fly to numerous international destinations including the UK.

Comment: i am asking about the safety of the site , not the airway.I had a problem buying from this site 3 years ago , 890 usd charged for 3 person reservation and i could not issue the tickets.someone bought ticket from this website?

Comment: If you had a problem before (that it wasn't fixed it seems), why would you buy a ticket from them again?

Answer (score 4):

> **Is it safe?**

Well, it's certainly not safe enough for me to send my credit card details over this site. Here's why:

- Website is not encrypted and does not allow encryption:[image]
- It does not matter that the flight selection site (https://booking.sita.aero/itd/itd/Air) is encrypted, you will afterwards be redirected again to a page for the credit card payment which is again partially unencrypted (verified with a http proxy tool).
- A Whois lookup reveals the following: [image]
- I suspect that this site is highly susceptible to being hacked (IIS 7.5 has at least one known vulnerability: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/15803)
- The server located on UAE territory will invariably collect your personal information.

[Even though](http://iraqiairways.com.iq/terms-and-conditions.html) they claim differently:

> All credit/debit card transactions are carried out on behalf of Iraqi
> Airways ([www.ia.com.iq](http://www.ia.com.iq)) by Barclays EPDQ Merchant bank PLC (after
> ticketing confirmation the user is forwarded to a secure payment
> system guaranteed by Barclays EPDQ Merchant bank PLC where the user
> may pay for their booking).

---

> **Can you print the issued ticket immediately after the purchase?**

No. It will be processed first and you likely have to wait up to 24 hrs before you get an email confirmation with the ticket issued.

---

**Solution**: Normally in such cases I call the UK office (+44 207 724 8455) and book through the agent, or I use a local travel agent service asking them to book the segments through their direct GDS connection. Last but not least (in case your inquiry is about domestic flights), flying in Iraq used to be cheaper with hard cash (USD) paid upon arrival after some negotiating.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but the security of the marketing site (iraqiairways.com.iq) is not really relevant here since they don't have your booking or payment info.  The booking site, SITA, is widely useful and generally trustworthy.  That said, I tried making a dummy booking, but the site seems sufficiently broken that I couldn't actually get to the final payment page to confirm...

Comment: @lambshaanxy The booking site is safe (https://booking.sita.aero/itd/ with a 256 bit certificate), however when I tried the payment (DXB/BGW can be bought for 350$ one way) redirection from my account, it uses a mix of http/https as seen in my proxy tool. So yes, the "marketing" is unsafe, the booking site (including account/profile) is safe, but I still would not trust the payment integration. Last but not least, having three sites with different registrars does not spread confidence.